How can I annotate a ListLogLinearPlot with Graphics and Text?
I'm running an incredibly old version of Mathematica: version 9.0 (how embarassing!).

I have a list of (x, y) ordered pairs that I can plot using ListPlot.
In the minimal working example (MWE) below, cosData is my list of
ordered pairs.
I like to "annotate" my ListPlots with additional plot points and Graphics
objects (specifically, styled Text). In the MWE below, the
first Show object (with the heading (* ListPlot example *))
demonstrates this.
Now suppose that I need to re-plot the data with the horizontal axis
having a logarithmic scale. This can be done using
ListLogLinearPlot, as shown in the second Show object ((* ListLogLinearPlot example *)) below. However, when I attempt to annotate with ListPlot and Graphics using Show, the annotations do not appear on the plot, as demonstrated in the second Show object below.
I have found that the red circle annotation can be displayed by simply changing ListPlot to ListLogLinearPlot, as shown in the third Show object ((* revised ListLogLinearPlot example *)) below. But the text annotation, using Graphics with real two-dimensional coordinates, does not appear.

So, my question is: how can I add coordinate-based Graphics/Text to a ListLogLinearPlot, using the tools available in Mathematica 9.0?
cosData = Table[{N[x], N[Cos[x]]}, {x, 0, 13 Pi, Pi/20}];
pointOfInterest = {18.8496, 1.0};
plotMarkerSize = 0.1;

(* ListPlot example *)
Show[{
  ListPlot[cosData, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, Frame -> True, 
   Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  ListPlot[{pointOfInterest}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}], plotMarkerSize}],
  Graphics[
   Text[Style["This is an annotation.", FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
    pointOfInterest, {-1, -2.5}]
   ]
  }]


cosData = Table[{N[x], N[Cos[x]]}, {x, 0, 13 Pi, Pi/20}];
pointOfInterest = {18.8496, 1.0};
plotMarkerSize = 0.1;

(* ListLogLinearPlot example *)
Show[{
  ListLogLinearPlot[cosData, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, Frame -> True, 
   Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  ListPlot[{pointOfInterest}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}], plotMarkerSize}],
  Graphics[
   Text[Style["This is an annotation.", 
     FontFamily -> "Arial"], {18.8496, 1.0}, {-1, -1}]
   ]
  }]


cosData = Table[{N[x], N[Cos[x]]}, {x, 0, 13 Pi, Pi/20}];
pointOfInterest = {18.8496, 1.0};
plotMarkerSize = 0.1;

(* revised ListLogLinearPlot example *)
Show[{
  ListLogLinearPlot[cosData, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, Frame -> True, 
   Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  ListLogLinearPlot[{pointOfInterest}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}], plotMarkerSize}],
  Graphics[
   Text[Style["This is an annotation.", 
     FontFamily -> "Arial"], {18.8496, 1.0}, {-1, -1}]
   ]
  }]



I think this is probably compatible with v9
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

cosData = Table[{N[x], N[Cos[x]]}, {x, 0, 13  Pi, Pi/20}];

pointOfInterest = {18.8496, 1.0};
plotMarkerSize = 0.1;

Show[{ListLogLinearPlot[cosData, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, 
   Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  ListLogLinearPlot[{pointOfInterest}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}], plotMarkerSize}], 
  Graphics[
   Text[Style["This is an\nannotation", 
     FontFamily -> "Arial"], {Log[18.8496], 1.0}, {-1, -1}]]}]


